# Creating dynamics columns in sql

Tags: sql-server

I want to create a stored procedure that takes `REQUEST_ID` as a parameter. I have the following table:

```
SELECT 
    [REQUEST_ID],
    [ITEM_ID],
    [ErrorType]
FROM
    (SELECT 
         [REQUEST_ID],
         [ITEM_ID],
         [ITEM_STATUS_DESC],
         CASE
            WHEN [ITEM_STATUS_DESC] LIKE 'Error:%- KS%'
               THEN SUBSTRING([ITEM_STATUS_DESC], LEN(LEFT([ITEM_STATUS_DESC], CHARINDEX('- 
 ', [ITEM_STATUS_DESC]))) + 2, 9)
            WHEN [ITEM_STATUS_DESC] LIKE 'Error:%(109)%'
               THEN 'Under construction'
            WHEN [ITEM_STATUS_DESC] LIKE 'Error:%(101)%'
               THEN 'Changed'
            ELSE 'Other error'
         END [ErrorType]
     FROM 
         [dbo].[X]
     WHERE 
         [REQUEST_ID] > 6000 AND [ITEM_STATUS_CD] > 1) [subQuery];
```

Output:

```
REQUEST_ID    ITEM_ID        ErrorType
---------------------------------------------------
6019          5054257        Under construction
6024          5054712        KSCV417W 
6024          5054713        Under construction
6024          5054715        Under construction
6029          5164288        KSAC680E 
6029          5164289        KSAC680E 
6029          5164290        KSAC680E 
6029          5164292        KSAC680E
```

I want the stored procedure to return the count of each `ErrorType` (are not fixed) for each `Request_ID`

Similar to :

```
REQUEST_ID    Under construction    KSCV417W     KSAC680E    KSPN690E 
---------------------------------------------------------------------
6019                1               
6024                2                  1
6029                                                4           1
```

Comment: This is going to be a dynamic cross tab or dynamic pivot. It has been asked and answered hundreds of times. Search this site for dynamic pivot. Or see this for dynamic cross tab. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Crosstab/65048/

Comment: Anyone willing to try to answer my question ? :)

Comment: Did you try the link I sent you? It explains how to do this type of thing quite clearly.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to enjoy this type of challenge so I took this one on. It is a little different than the standard dynamic cross tab because the column names are also dynamic. Please note that this does not return KSPN690E because that was not in the sample data you provided.

I used the techniques found in the Jeff Moden article found here. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Crosstab/65048/

```
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Something') is not null
    drop table #Something

if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#ColumnNames') is not null
    drop table #ColumnNames

create table #Something
(
    REQUEST_ID int
    , ITEM_ID int
    , ErrorType varchar(50)
)

insert #Something values
(6019, 5054257, 'Under construction')
, (6024, 5054712, 'KSCV417W')
, (6024, 5054713, 'Under construction')
, (6024, 5054715, 'Under construction')
, (6029, 5164288, 'KSAC680E')
, (6029, 5164289, 'KSAC680E')
, (6029, 5164290, 'KSAC680E')
, (6029, 5164292, 'KSAC680E')

create table #ColumnNames --we need some way to get the Column Names in a table so we can join to this to generate the dynamic columns.
(
    ColNum int identity
    , ColName sysname
)

insert #ColumnNames
select distinct ErrorType
from #Something
order by ErrorType desc

declare @StaticPortion nvarchar(2000) = 
'with OrderedResults as
(
    select REQUEST_ID
        , ErrorType
        , GroupCount = count(*)
        , ColNum
    from #Something s
    join #ColumnNames cn on cn.ColName = s.ErrorType
    group by REQUEST_ID
        , ErrorType
        , ColNum
)
select REQUEST_ID';

declare @DynamicPortion nvarchar(max) = '';


with E1(N) AS (select 1 from (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))dt(n)),
E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
cteTally(N) AS 
(
    SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
)

select @DynamicPortion = @DynamicPortion + 
    ', MAX(Case when ColNum = ' + CAST(N as varchar(6)) + ' then convert(varchar(4), GroupCount) end) as [' + cn.ColName + ']'
from cteTally t
join #ColumnNames cn on cn.ColNum = t.N
where t.N <= 
(
    select top 1 Count(*)
    from #Something
    group by REQUEST_ID
    order by COUNT(*) desc
)

declare @FinalStaticPortion nvarchar(2000) = ' from OrderedResults Group by REQUEST_ID order by REQUEST_ID';

declare @SqlToExecute nvarchar(max) = @StaticPortion + @DynamicPortion + @FinalStaticPortion;

--select @SqlToExecute --You can use this to help debug the dynamic sql

exec sp_executesql @SqlToExecute
```